# How can I create a dynamic input field that will update width based on a label inside the input

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a date input field that looks like this

[image]

Currently my css is set up so that the label is just floating above the input (I know, not the best) and overlaps the date value if I change the label to something with a greater character length.
What is the best way I can place the label itself inside the input so that the width of the field is dependent on the length of the label?

My input component

```
<div className={`custom-input-container ${required ? 'required' : ''}`}>
<label
          className="date-label inline-label"
          data-content={label}
          htmlFor={id}
        >
          {label}
        </label>
        <input
          className="input-with-inline-label"
          type="text"
          id={id}
          onClick={onClick}
          value={value}
        />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I found that you can get the width of the label component by using its ref prop to set the state width value

```
const [width,setWidth] = useState(0)

const CustomInput = ({ value, onClick }) => {
<div className={`custom-input-container ${required ? 'required' : ''}`}>
        <label
          className="date-label inline-label"
          data-content={label}
          htmlFor={id}
          ref={(el) => {
            if (!el) return
            setWidth(el.getBoundingClientRect().width)
          }}
        >
          {label}
        </label>
        <input
          className="input-with-inline-label"
          type="text"
          onClick={onClick}
          value={value}
          style={{
            width: `${width + 140}px`,
            minWidth: '150px',
          }}
        />
}
```

This is with the following css in place

```
.inline-label {
          position: absolute;
          top: 2px;
          padding: 0 0 0 8px;

        }

        .input-with-inline-label {
          text-align: right;
        }
```